# How to access firebreath plugin from Internet Explorer Extension

Tags: internet-explorer, plugins, firebreath, ieaddon

I have created extensions for chrome, firefox and safari which can use firebreath plugin by defining an object in background.html or panel.html and then interacting with plugin functionalities using js.

I am completely at a dead end for IE Extensions.

What I have tried so far it to create a context menu or tool's menu using registry, now I am not sure how can I use the firebreath plugin . Where to start ?

I am looking for a simple sample code or steps which can solve the above problem.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I don't even know how IE extensions work, so I have no idea.  You may have to load it using ActiveX, and I don't even know if that's totally possible

Answer (score 0):

Firebreath Plugins are added as Active X objects in Windows. We can access active X objects via any thing viz (javascript, C# programs , etc etc).

For simulating normal behaviours as we get in firefox or chrome extension , you need to create BHO (Browser Helper Objects) which gives functionality to interact with Content Page. BHO will act as content script.

BHO is created in Visual Studio using C#. More details on how to create BHO can be found at codeproject.com